# what is the difference between int:gatway vs int-ws:inbound-gatway or int-ws:outbound-gatway in spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have seen `<int:gateway ..../>` configuration in some place and `<int-jms:inbound-gateway ../>` or `<int-ws:outbound-gateway ../>`  in other place or together in spring integration configuration. I am not able to find out the main differences between them.

I got that gatway's are two way connection. then

- As the `int:gatway` can be used both directional communication, can't we use it in place of other `inbound/outbound gatway`? - I beleive the answer will be they are used for specific type of request like `WS` or `JMS` to do specific task. But still I am confused if the same can be done using the `int:gatway`.
- Also What is the use of `int:gatway` if there are specific type of gatway present for all different services ( like JMS or WS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an `<int:gateway/>` as a gateway from legacy java code into a messaging flow.

```
public interface MyGate {

    Bar fooToBar(Foo foo);

}
```

Then, in legacy java code (e.g. a REST Controller), you "send" a Foo which is wrapped in a message and the flow returns a Bar in the reply Payload and the framework unwraps it for you.

The client code does not know it was interacting with a messaging system.

The end of the flow, for example, might call a `<ws:outbound-gateway/>`.

So, the gateway abstracts away from the messaging from the client's perspective.

Comment: Thanks Gary. That really make sense.